# Отправить файл из проводника в приложение

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Мне нужно отправить файл (неважно какого расширения) в **собственное** приложение на android из проводника, так же , как показано на скрине.

Но я без понятия как это организовать.

Как сделать , чтобы мое приложение отображалось в этом списке (vk, Bluetooth и тд)?

И как принять этот файл внутри ?

помогите пожалуйста))[image]

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо хорошо понимать что такое `IntentFilter`. Также вы должны знать основы -> `Intent, Intent Actions, IntentChooser`. в Android Developer есть подходящий ответ, рекомендую сделать и всё станет на свои места https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно в манифест вашего приложения добавить интент-фильтры, указывающие на то что ваше приложение может принимать неявные интенты:

```
activity android:name=".ui.MyActivity" >
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

Если пользователь захочет поделиться, например, изображением из галереи то система проверит манифесты всех установленных приложений на аппарате и предложит ему выбрать из тех в которых есть `intent-filter <data android:mimeType="image/*" />`